# Как правильно добавлять изображения?

Tags: android, imageview

Создал Layout с расчётом на дисплей 1080x1920 320dpi. Добавил на layout ImageView с изображением из drawable/image.png. Размер этого самого изображения 350x150px, но по факту на Layout оно получается по всю ширину экрана и если задавать **android:layout_width** и **android:layout_height** как "wrap_content".
Почему так?

Как правильно разместить изображение того размера, какого оно должно быть?

Comment: Я бы взглянул на саму разметку

Comment: как минимум, покладите изображение в соответствующую DPI папку. Для 320 DPI это `xhdpi`

Comment: а почему сразу не сделать ассет из имиджа, андройд сам определит какое изображение использовать в зависимости от размера экрана?